# EPPLUS export to excel protected View Issue ; Updated with previous Working Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel, epplus

I am able to export GridView to Excel successfully using Epplus. I have an issue that the excel is opening in **protected view** mode and  I have to explicitly click on **enable editing** button to edit. I want that the excel should generate directly in **enable editing** mode.
I was able to do it without Epplus but I dont know how to do it with epplus.
Here is the screenshot : 
[image]

Here is my Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table;
using System.Data;  

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridData.xlsx");
        // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

       using(ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
       {
         ExcelWorksheet wsDt = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
         wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true, TableStyles.None);
         wsDt.Cells[wsDt.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

         wsDt.Protection.IsProtected = false;
         Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
       }

       Response.Flush();
       Response.End();
    }
}
```

**Update** Here is the Code that opens the excel file directly in "Enable Editing mode" :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table;
using System.Data;  

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridData.xls");
        // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

       //using(ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
       //{
       //  ExcelWorksheet wsDt = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
       //  wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true, TableStyles.None);
       //  wsDt.Cells[wsDt.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

       //  wsDt.Protection.IsProtected = false;
       //  Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
       //}

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = table;
        gv.DataBind();

        gv.RenderControl(htw);
       Response.Write(sw.ToString());
       Response.Flush();
       Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is an Excel feature, where it protects the Excel sheet because it was downloaded from the Internet. I don't think this can be solved by Epplus, or any other way of generating the Excel file. How did you get this to work without Epplus?

Comment: No.. actually before Epplus i was able to generate excel directly in "enable editing" mode and now also If I uses my previous code it successfully generates excel in Enable Editing mode. But I cannot go with my previous code as it supports only excel files that can hold 65000 records. Now we are getting nearly 100K records to handle them we have to use epplus and I don't know to how to disable protected View using epplus.

Comment: Here is a description of the protected view:
https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/What-is-Protected-View-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653

Can you show the code where you solved this without Epplus?

Comment: sorry Mr. Martin I cant show you the code right now. But I doing it and hence I have posted to get it resolved with epplus. Believe me!

Comment: Can I get a proper answer here? :(

Comment: @MartinBennedik I have updated with the new code.. Could you please look into it.